# PHP MySQL как получить последнее Id

Tags: php, sql

Пытаюсь просто получить последнее id с помощью 'insert_id', и я посмотрел как это сделать
здесь (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp), но у меня пишет id = 0
Может сейчас уже как то по другому нужно получать последнее id, просто я не понимаю
почему этот метод не работает, вот мой код если что ↓

```
          <?php 
                    $servername = "localhost";
                    $username = "root";
                    $password = "";
                    $dbname = "pocztadb";
                    $wlasciciel = $_SESSION["nick"];
                    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                    if ($conn->connect_error) {
                        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                    }



                    // вот здесь я пытаюсь его получить ↓
                    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;



                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wiadomosci WHERE wlasciciel='$wlasciciel' AND
                            katalog='Odebrane' AND id > $last_id ORDER BY data";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);
                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {



                    //здесь вывожу и у меня пишет "last id = 0" ↓
                    echo "<h1>last id = " . $last_id . "</h1>";



                } else {
                    echo "brak";
                } 
                        $conn->close();
          ?>
```

Comment: после запроса к бд его получает, а не до. И вообще это относится к INSERT

Comment: Чтобы получить `last_id`, нужно сначала выполнить запрос с `INSERT`. Что Вы в коде своём пытаетесь сделать — загадка.